# What is the difference between initialising an object with and without a constructor call in C++

Tags: c++, class

In C++14 When we have

```
class A{};
```

and if we initialize an object of class `A` in the form below

```
A a = A();
```

not traditionally

```
A a;
```

So what happens in `A a = A();` ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. With your given code snippets and compiler optimization nothing will happen because `a` is not used.

Comment: Nitpick: `A a = A()` *isn't* an expression. `A a = A();` is a statement. The `;` is required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before C++17, copy elision might happen else you have move/copy constructor call but anyway the move/copy constructor should be available.

Since C++17, no copy/move constructor happens (and doesn't need neither to be accessible).

Comment: Additionally, `A a = A();`  value-initializes the object, while `A a;` default-initializes it.